# Shell Script For Python Throws ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to run a python script at start for my Raspberry Pi 3B.
My shell script "atboot.sh" looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/pi/pythoncodefolder
date >> logs
sudo python3 test.py >> logs
```

When I try to run it on cmd with `sh atboot.sh` command, I get an import error which is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
        import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

But when I run the program on cmd without shell script, using `python3 test.py`, I get no errors.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably because of another user enviroment is used, because of `sudo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `sudo` causing it. When you run `python3 program.py` you invoke it in your `$USER` environment setup.

You can remove `Defaults !env_reset` from sudoers. Or to add `Defaults env_keep += "PYTHONPATH"`.

But I would assert that you can **do it without** `sudo` in the first place.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/pi/pythoncodefolder
date >> logs
python3 test.py >> logs
```

*Also, that's probably a (not exact) duplicate.*

Comment: Yeah, removing sudo solved the problem. Thanks.